# Custom section header view for UITableView appears on simulator, but not on iPhone.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Here's the deal, I've implemented a UITableView with custom expandable sections that expand when clicked to display more cells that are selectable. The problem I'm running into is that it works perfectly on the simulator (for both 4" and 3.5"), yet when I run it on an actual phone (4") it displays an empty table view. The custom section header that I use is an .xib file and all of the labels inside the expandable section header and the cells "inside it" are dynamically populated from a .plist. To do all this I pieced together some sample code from the iOS Developer Library site, found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

Then I just customized it to fit my project and make it work. As far as I've seen, all my files are on the app not just referenced to. A lot of this is new stuff to me, so I'm not really sure where to look or what exactly to provide to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between Simulator and Device is that the `Simulator is case-insensitive` and the `device case-sensitive`.

If the images are loading from your resources and they show on the simulator only, first thing to do is **check upper-/lower-case differences between filenames and the code that binds the files to elements**.

--
edit: also watch out when naming the images in Storyboard!

[image: storuboardupperlowercase]

Comment: I've looked through my code and don't see any case differences, and the .xib file identifier is correct in the storyboard and when loaded in the code. I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm not using images (as your example shows) I'm loading a custom section header that is an .xib file.

Comment: Are you not using UIImages at allin the app? The xib file of the custom header section is also image-free?

Comment: I am using them throughout the app and in the .xib file, but all of the identifiers matched. The issue has actually resolved itself it seems...I'm not exactly sure how or why. The only thing I've changed is I turned on the "Target Membership" for the .plist and it worked, yet when I turn it off it still works. Very strange.

Comment: Strange indeed.. well I'll leave my answer up, maybe somebody else can benefit from it.